# image shown in modal but has a white background

Tags: css, image

I am using a css modal and it is not displaying as normal . it has a white background that is not supposed to be there. I have tried changing the background color but it does not work.

```
      /* Hide the slides by default */
      .mySlides {
       display: block;
       background-color: none;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

by default background should inherit its parent color, please add your HTML code as well for more details

check out the following as well

`background-color: none;`

is an invalid property, try following

`background-color: #ffffff00;`

the last two digits represent the opacity of color, 00 means opacity 0